# Is integrated circuit packaging copyrighted/patented?

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages, chip-design

A friend of mine is interested in manufacturing ICs. He wants to know whether the different form types of packages (DIP, LGA,  BGA) have intellectual property obstacles to using them. If so, who owns them and how are royalties paid?

Comment: I would have thought that was the least of his problems. If he's going to buy the lead frames then ask the vendor.

Comment: *"A friend of mine is interested in manufacturing ICs"* I hope your friend is independently wealthy.

Comment: why is your friend not asking this question?

Comment: @jsotola This comment is IMHO off-topic. It does not make any difference if a question is asked by proxy or directly. Relevant here are contents and perhaps format of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the common, industry-standard IC package types are covered by JEDEC standards. If there is an associated JEDEC standard code for the package, then the patent is held by a manufacturer who is a JEDEC member, and there are available license terms for the applicable patents.

More innovative packages might be covered by other patents which might not be available. If you want to make a plastic DIP 16 packages lead frame, that’s a common JEDEC standard part code **MS-001BE**. If you want to copy a unique device package that you found when for example you ripped open your iPhone, that may violate someone’s patent...

Sticking with standard package types makes it easier to test (because you can use standard ATE test handler fixtures), easier to ship (because you don’t need to develop your own tubes boxes bags etc), and easier for the end customer to use (existing Eagle CAD footprints).

Check the data sheet for any common part, look for the package drawing, and you will find many of them reference JEDEC standard package codes.

Comment: Can you give an example of a JEDEC standard package where the definition of the package itself is patented? Just because something is standardized does not mean that it is controlled by a patent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was reading about JEDEC and it sounds like you cannot patent a standard. Is that the case? Also, I could not find which JEDEC standard pertained to ic packages. At any rate, knowing about them definitely helps, and I think I can find these answers on my own.

Comment: You can have a patent on something that becomes a standard. That is why standards setting bodies require that participants in setting standards pre-agree that if they get patents on anything they are proposing in the standards process it will be licensed in a reasonable and non-discriminatory  manner (RAND).

Answer (score -1):

Be aware the thermal properties of a package will strongly depend on the (epoxy-filled) distance between the paddle and the stamped leads.

Having "better" thermal performance will not be an accident. and the failure rates will be lower.

You can use the awareness as a selling point.

Comment: This doesn't address the question in the title or in the post.